# Why isn't the 2nd click function working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click on one of the film pictures, the first click function works, it  `hide()` the other films & only displays the film clicked on.

The 2nd click function does not work. It displays a small cross, when this is clicked it is suppose to display all the 4 films again & `hide()` the description text for the film currently being shown.

**Why isn't this working, please?**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //$('.cross').hide();
  $('.movie').on('click', function() {
    $('.movie').hide();
    $(this).show().addClass('showmovie');
  }); // close .move click


  $('.movie').on('click', '.cross', function() {
    $(this).closest('.movie').hide().removeClass('showmovie');
    $('.movie').show();
  }); // close above function

}); //close document ready
```

```css
/*--------------------
Body
--------------------*/

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center top, #ffee75, #ff8930);
  color: #8b9095;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

@mixin center {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/*--------------------
App
--------------------*/

.app {
  @include center;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  -000000pp box-shadow: 0 5px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h2 {
  color: #525661;
  font-size: 17px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 20px 28px 0;
  margin: -6px 0 0 0;
}


/*--------------------
Header
--------------------*/

header {
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
  height: 70px;
  h1 {
    @include center;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: #1c222b;
    strong {
      background: #F16018;
      color: #fff;
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 30px;
      padding: 6px;
      font-size: 83%;
      line-height: 1;
      position: relative;
      top: -1px;
      left: 2px;
    }
  }
  nav {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 28px;
    left: 28px;
    &::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 2px;
      background: #363a47;
      border-radius: 2px;
      box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #363a47, 0 10px 0 #363a47;
    }
  }
  .search {
    position: absolute;
    top: 26px;
    right: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    svg {
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
    }
  }
}


/*--------------------
Movies
--------------------*/

.movies {
  display: flex;
  padding: 8px 18px;
}

.movie {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 25%;
}

.poster {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  &.active {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.title {
  //text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #525661;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.info {
  font-size: 11px;
  opacity: .8;
}

.desc {
  display: none;
}


}

}

/*--------------------
Detail
--------------------*/
.detail {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 37px 30px 30px 255px;
  display: none;
  &::before {
    content: '';
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(.67, .13, .1, .81);
  }
  .close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 21px;
    right: 22px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 6px solid #FFF;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  .poster {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: -10%;
    left: -6%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    //opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(.67, .13, .1, .81);
  }
  .title,
  .info,
  .desc,
  .play,
  .close {
    transform: translateX(-50px);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(.67, .13, .1, .81);
  }
  .close {
    transform: translateX(10px);
    ;
  }
  .title {
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #525661;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .info {
    font-size: 11px;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: 2px;
  }
  .desc {
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.6;
  }
  .play {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #E4761F, #FF8B32);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding: 8px 17px;
    margin: 30px 0 0 -2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index: 10;
    outline: none !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    svg {
      vertical-align: middle;
      position: relative;
      top: -2px;
      margin-right: 3px;
    }
  }
}
.detail.ready {
  &::before {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .info {
    opacity: .8;
  }
  .poster {
    opacity: 1;
    transition-duration: .5s;
  }
  .title,
  .info,
  .desc,
  .play,
  .close {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-duration: .5s;
  }
  .title {
    transition-delay: .2s;
  }
  .info {
    transition-delay: .3s;
  }
  .desc {
    transition-delay: .4s;
  }
  .play {
    transition-delay: .5s;
  }
}
//* {display: none;} *//
.cross {
  display: none;
}
.showmovie {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}
.showmovie>.title {
  font-size: 2em;
}
.showmovie>img {
  width: 250px;
}
.showmovie>.desc {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  display: block;
}
.showmovie>.cross {
  display: block;
}
.showmovie>.movie {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="app">
    <header>

      <nav></nav>
      <div class="search"><svg><use xlink:href="#ico-search"></use></svg></div>
    </header>

    <h2 class="titlec">Most Popular Movies</h2>
    <section class="movies">
      <div class="movie">
        <img src="https://github.com/supahfunk/supah-codepen/blob/master/movie-room.jpg?raw=true" alt="" class="poster" />
        <div class="title">Room</div>
        <div class="info">
          <span class="length">117 min</span>
          <span class="year">2015</span>
        </div>
        <div class="desc">

          <p>

            Jack is a young boy of 5 years old who has lived all his life in one room. He believes everything within it are the only real things in the world. But what will happen when his Ma suddenly tells him that there are other things outside of Room? </p>
        </div>
        <button class="play">  Play </button>
        <a href="#" class="cross room" aria-label="Close Account Info Modal Box">&times;</a>
      </div>
      <!-- close .movie -->
      <div class="movie">
        <img src="https://github.com/supahfunk/supah-codepen/blob/master/movie-whiplash.jpg?raw=true" alt="" class="poster" />
        <div class="title">Whiplash</div>
        <div class="info">
          <span class="length">167 min</span>
          <span class="year">2015</span>
        </div>
        <div class="desc">
          Under the direction of a ruthless instructor, a talented young drummer begins to pursue perfection at any cost, even his humanity.
        </div>
        <button class="play">  Play  </button>
        <a href="#" class="cross" aria-label="Close Account Info Modal Box">&times;</a>
      </div>
      <!-- close .movie -->
      <div class="movie">
        <img src="https://github.com/supahfunk/supah-codepen/blob/master/movie-madmax.jpg?raw=true" alt="" class="poster" />
        <div class="title">Mad Max</div>
        <div class="info">
          <span class="length">120 min</span>
          <span class="year">2015</span>
        </div>
        <div class="desc">
          An apocalyptic story set in the furthest reaches of our planet, in a stark desert landscape where humanity is broken, and most everyone is crazed fighting for the necessities of life. Within this world exist two rebels on the run who just might be able
          to restore order. There's Max, a man of action and a man of few words, who seeks peace of mind following the loss of his wife and child in the aftermath of the chaos.
        </div>
        <button class="play"> Play </button>
        <a href="#" class="cross" aria-label="Close Account Info Modal Box">&times;</a>
      </div>
      <!-- close .movie-->
      <div class="movie">
        <img src="https://github.com/supahfunk/supah-codepen/blob/master/movie-therevenant.jpg?raw=true" alt="" class="poster" />
        <div class="title">The Revenant</div>
        <div class="info">
          <span class="length">156 min</span>
          <span class="year">2015</span>
        </div>
        <div class="desc">
          In the 1820s, a frontiersman, Hugh Glass, sets out on a path of vengeance against those who left him for dead after a bear mauling.
        </div>
        <button class="play">  Play </button>
        <a href="#" class="cross" aria-label="Close Account Info Modal Box">&times;</a>
      </div>
      <!-- close .movie-->
    </section>

  </div>
  <!--close .app -->

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click event on your close cross button bubbles up the DOM and then triggers the click event you bound on the parent `.movie` div. You can easily stop this by adding `e.stopPropagation();` to your code. No extra variables or if conditions necessary.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //$('.cross').hide();
  $('.movie').on('click', function() {
    $('.movie').hide();
    $(this).show().addClass('showmovie');
  }); // close .move click


  $('.movie').on('click', '.cross', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest('.movie').hide().removeClass('showmovie');
    $('.movie').show();
  }); // close above function

}); //close document ready
```

```css
/*--------------------
Body
--------------------*/

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center top, #ffee75, #ff8930);
  color: #8b9095;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

@mixin center {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/*--------------------
App
--------------------*/

.app {
  @include center;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  -000000pp box-shadow: 0 5px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h2 {
  color: #525661;
  font-size: 17px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 20px 28px 0;
  margin: -6px 0 0 0;
}


/*--------------------
Header
--------------------*/

header {
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
  height: 70px;
  h1 {
    @include center;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: #1c222b;
    strong {
      background: #F16018;
      color: #fff;
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 30px;
      padding: 6px;
      font-size: 83%;
      line-height: 1;
      position: relative;
      top: -1px;
      left: 2px;
    }
  }
  nav {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 28px;
    left: 28px;
    &::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 2px;
      background: #363a47;
      border-radius: 2px;
      box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #363a47, 0 10px 0 #363a47;
    }
  }
  .search {
    position: absolute;
    top: 26px;
    right: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    svg {
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
    }
  }
}


/*--------------------
Movies
--------------------*/

.movies {
  display: flex;
  padding: 8px 18px;
}

.movie {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 25%;
}

.poster {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  &.active {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.title {
  //text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #525661;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.info {
  font-size: 11px;
  opacity: .8;
}

.desc {
  display: none;
}


}

}

/*--------------------
Detail
--------------------*/
.detail {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 37px 30px 30px 255px;
  display: none;
  &::before {
    content: '';
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(.67, .13, .1, .81);
  }
  .close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 21px;
    right: 22px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 6px solid #FFF;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  .poster {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: -10%;
    left: -6%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    //opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(.67, .13, .1, .81);
  }
  .title,
  .info,
  .desc,
  .play,
  .close {
    transform: translateX(-50px);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(.67, .13, .1, .81);
  }
  .close {
    transform: translateX(10px);
    ;
  }
  .title {
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #525661;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .info {
    font-size: 11px;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: 2px;
  }
  .desc {
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.6;
  }
  .play {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #E4761F, #FF8B32);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding: 8px 17px;
    margin: 30px 0 0 -2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index: 10;
    outline: none !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    svg {
      vertical-align: middle;
      position: relative;
      top: -2px;
      margin-right: 3px;
    }
  }
}
.detail.ready {
  &::before {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .info {
    opacity: .8;
  }
  .poster {
    opacity: 1;
    transition-duration: .5s;
  }
  .title,
  .info,
  .desc,
  .play,
  .close {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-duration: .5s;
  }
  .title {
    transition-delay: .2s;
  }
  .info {
    transition-delay: .3s;
  }
  .desc {
    transition-delay: .4s;
  }
  .play {
    transition-delay: .5s;
  }
}
//* {display: none;} *//
.cross {
  display: none;
}
.showmovie {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}
.showmovie>.title {
  font-size: 2em;
}
.showmovie>img {
  width: 250px;
}
.showmovie>.desc {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  display: block;
}
.showmovie>.cross {
  display: block;
}
.showmovie>.movie {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="app">
    <header>

      <nav></nav>
      <div class="search"><svg><use xlink:href="#ico-search"></use></svg></div>
    </header>

    <h2 class="titlec">Most Popular Movies</h2>
    <section class="movies">
      <div class="movie">
        <img src="https://github.com/supahfunk/supah-codepen/blob/master/movie-room.jpg?raw=true" alt="" class="poster" />
        <div class="title">Room</div>
        <div class="info">
          <span class="length">117 min</span>
          <span class="year">2015</span>
        </div>
        <div class="desc">

          <p>

            Jack is a young boy of 5 years old who has lived all his life in one room. He believes everything within it are the only real things in the world. But what will happen when his Ma suddenly tells him that there are other things outside of Room? </p>
        </div>
        <button class="play">  Play </button>
        <a href="#" class="cross room" aria-label="Close Account Info Modal Box">&times;</a>
      </div>
      <!-- close .movie -->
      <div class="movie">
        <img src="https://github.com/supahfunk/supah-codepen/blob/master/movie-whiplash.jpg?raw=true" alt="" class="poster" />
        <div class="title">Whiplash</div>
        <div class="info">
          <span class="length">167 min</span>
          <span class="year">2015</span>
        </div>
        <div class="desc">
          Under the direction of a ruthless instructor, a talented young drummer begins to pursue perfection at any cost, even his humanity.
        </div>
        <button class="play">  Play  </button>
        <a href="#" class="cross" aria-label="Close Account Info Modal Box">&times;</a>
      </div>
      <!-- close .movie -->
      <div class="movie">
        <img src="https://github.com/supahfunk/supah-codepen/blob/master/movie-madmax.jpg?raw=true" alt="" class="poster" />
        <div class="title">Mad Max</div>
        <div class="info">
          <span class="length">120 min</span>
          <span class="year">2015</span>
        </div>
        <div class="desc">
          An apocalyptic story set in the furthest reaches of our planet, in a stark desert landscape where humanity is broken, and most everyone is crazed fighting for the necessities of life. Within this world exist two rebels on the run who just might be able
          to restore order. There's Max, a man of action and a man of few words, who seeks peace of mind following the loss of his wife and child in the aftermath of the chaos.
        </div>
        <button class="play"> Play </button>
        <a href="#" class="cross" aria-label="Close Account Info Modal Box">&times;</a>
      </div>
      <!-- close .movie-->
      <div class="movie">
        <img src="https://github.com/supahfunk/supah-codepen/blob/master/movie-therevenant.jpg?raw=true" alt="" class="poster" />
        <div class="title">The Revenant</div>
        <div class="info">
          <span class="length">156 min</span>
          <span class="year">2015</span>
        </div>
        <div class="desc">
          In the 1820s, a frontiersman, Hugh Glass, sets out on a path of vengeance against those who left him for dead after a bear mauling.
        </div>
        <button class="play">  Play </button>
        <a href="#" class="cross" aria-label="Close Account Info Modal Box">&times;</a>
      </div>
      <!-- close .movie-->
    </section>

  </div>
  <!--close .app -->

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you bind the `click` event twice (which is just cause both of the handlers to be fired).

Instead, you need to bind it once but check of which state you are. I'm doing this by holding a boolean variable which says if I in the "list state" (`isMovieSelected = false`) or in "movie state" (`isMovieSelected = true`)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var isMovieSelected = false;
  //$('.cross').hide();
  $('.movie').on('click', function() {
    if (isMovieSelected) {
      $(this).closest('.movie').hide().removeClass('showmovie');
      $('.movie').show();  
    } else {
      $('.movie').hide();
      $(this).show().addClass('showmovie');
    }
    
    isMovieSelected = !isMovieSelected;
  }); // close .move click
}); //close document ready
```

```css
/*--------------------
Body
--------------------*/

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center top, #ffee75, #ff8930);
  color: #8b9095;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

@mixin center {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/*--------------------
App
--------------------*/

.app {
  @include center;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  -000000pp box-shadow: 0 5px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h2 {
  color: #525661;
  font-size: 17px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 20px 28px 0;
  margin: -6px 0 0 0;
}


/*--------------------
Header
--------------------*/

header {
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
  height: 70px;
  h1 {
    @include center;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: #1c222b;
    strong {
      background: #F16018;
      color: #fff;
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 30px;
      padding: 6px;
      font-size: 83%;
      line-height: 1;
      position: relative;
      top: -1px;
      left: 2px;
    }
  }
  nav {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 28px;
    left: 28px;
    &::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 2px;
      background: #363a47;
      border-radius: 2px;
      box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #363a47, 0 10px 0 #363a47;
    }
  }
  .search {
    position: absolute;
    top: 26px;
    right: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    svg {
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
    }
  }
}


/*--------------------
Movies
--------------------*/

.movies {
  display: flex;
  padding: 8px 18px;
}

.movie {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 25%;
}

.poster {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  &.active {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.title {
  //text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #525661;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.info {
  font-size: 11px;
  opacity: .8;
}

.desc {
  display: none;
}


}

}

/*--------------------
Detail
--------------------*/
.detail {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 37px 30px 30px 255px;
  display: none;
  &::before {
    content: '';
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(.67, .13, .1, .81);
  }
  .close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 21px;
    right: 22px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 6px solid #FFF;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  .poster {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: -10%;
    left: -6%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    //opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(.67, .13, .1, .81);
  }
  .title,
  .info,
  .desc,
  .play,
  .close {
    transform: translateX(-50px);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(.67, .13, .1, .81);
  }
  .close {
    transform: translateX(10px);
    ;
  }
  .title {
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #525661;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .info {
    font-size: 11px;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: 2px;
  }
  .desc {
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.6;
  }
  .play {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #E4761F, #FF8B32);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding: 8px 17px;
    margin: 30px 0 0 -2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index: 10;
    outline: none !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    svg {
      vertical-align: middle;
      position: relative;
      top: -2px;
      margin-right: 3px;
    }
  }
}
.detail.ready {
  &::before {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .info {
    opacity: .8;
  }
  .poster {
    opacity: 1;
    transition-duration: .5s;
  }
  .title,
  .info,
  .desc,
  .play,
  .close {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-duration: .5s;
  }
  .title {
    transition-delay: .2s;
  }
  .info {
    transition-delay: .3s;
  }
  .desc {
    transition-delay: .4s;
  }
  .play {
    transition-delay: .5s;
  }
}
//* {display: none;} *//
.cross {
  display: none;
}
.showmovie {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}
.showmovie>.title {
  font-size: 2em;
}
.showmovie>img {
  width: 250px;
}
.showmovie>.desc {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  display: block;
}
.showmovie>.cross {
  display: block;
}
.showmovie>.movie {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="app">
    <header>

      <nav></nav>
      <div class="search"><svg><use xlink:href="#ico-search"></use></svg></div>
    </header>

    <h2 class="titlec">Most Popular Movies</h2>
    <section class="movies">
      <div class="movie">
        <img src="https://github.com/supahfunk/supah-codepen/blob/master/movie-room.jpg?raw=true" alt="" class="poster" />
        <div class="title">Room</div>
        <div class="info">
          <span class="length">117 min</span>
          <span class="year">2015</span>
        </div>
        <div class="desc">

          <p>

            Jack is a young boy of 5 years old who has lived all his life in one room. He believes everything within it are the only real things in the world. But what will happen when his Ma suddenly tells him that there are other things outside of Room? </p>
        </div>
        <button class="play">  Play </button>
        <a href="#" class="cross room" aria-label="Close Account Info Modal Box">&times;</a>
      </div>
      <!-- close .movie -->
      <div class="movie">
        <img src="https://github.com/supahfunk/supah-codepen/blob/master/movie-whiplash.jpg?raw=true" alt="" class="poster" />
        <div class="title">Whiplash</div>
        <div class="info">
          <span class="length">167 min</span>
          <span class="year">2015</span>
        </div>
        <div class="desc">
          Under the direction of a ruthless instructor, a talented young drummer begins to pursue perfection at any cost, even his humanity.
        </div>
        <button class="play">  Play  </button>
        <a href="#" class="cross" aria-label="Close Account Info Modal Box">&times;</a>
      </div>
      <!-- close .movie -->
      <div class="movie">
        <img src="https://github.com/supahfunk/supah-codepen/blob/master/movie-madmax.jpg?raw=true" alt="" class="poster" />
        <div class="title">Mad Max</div>
        <div class="info">
          <span class="length">120 min</span>
          <span class="year">2015</span>
        </div>
        <div class="desc">
          An apocalyptic story set in the furthest reaches of our planet, in a stark desert landscape where humanity is broken, and most everyone is crazed fighting for the necessities of life. Within this world exist two rebels on the run who just might be able
          to restore order. There's Max, a man of action and a man of few words, who seeks peace of mind following the loss of his wife and child in the aftermath of the chaos.
        </div>
        <button class="play"> Play </button>
        <a href="#" class="cross" aria-label="Close Account Info Modal Box">&times;</a>
      </div>
      <!-- close .movie-->
      <div class="movie">
        <img src="https://github.com/supahfunk/supah-codepen/blob/master/movie-therevenant.jpg?raw=true" alt="" class="poster" />
        <div class="title">The Revenant</div>
        <div class="info">
          <span class="length">156 min</span>
          <span class="year">2015</span>
        </div>
        <div class="desc">
          In the 1820s, a frontiersman, Hugh Glass, sets out on a path of vengeance against those who left him for dead after a bear mauling.
        </div>
        <button class="play">  Play </button>
        <a href="#" class="cross" aria-label="Close Account Info Modal Box">&times;</a>
      </div>
      <!-- close .movie-->
    </section>

  </div>
  <!--close .app -->

</body>

</html>
```